# Can't connect to SQL Azure instance from local computer using SSMS or ODBC (error 10060)

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Before the last Windows 10 update I was able to connect to my SQL Azure instance from my local PC using ODBC or SSMS.  An update ran overnight and now I can't connect from my computer anymore (it is not a VM, it is my host computer).  Although I ***can*** connect from any other computer using the same credentials.  I tried turning off my Firewall and that didn't fix the problem.

[image: Screenshot from SSMS Error Message]

Comment: Did you add your computer's public ip address to the SQL Database firewall? If not, you won't be able to connect.

Comment: Yes, I did.  In fact I set it to accept all IP addresses (0.0.0.0 through 255.255.255.255) because I am testing across multiple devices for now.  I haven't changed anything on the SQL Azure side at all.  So the fact that it connected from my PC one day and then not the next is puzzling.  I verified that I can connect from multiple other devices without problems.

Comment: Did you try with your DB as default database in server connection window (diff tab) ?

Comment: @ArunVinoth I doubt that, in that case you would receive 'Cannot open database "DBNAME" requested by the login. The login failed.' This still look like network issue on client machine to me.

Comment: if ip is an issue,the error will be different,try adding port number name,1433 and can you try again

Comment: I tried using the original server name with ,1433 at the end and get the same message as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed the problem, but I can't really say what caused it.  I deleted all SQL Server 2017 components, then reinstalled SSMS 17.1 and now I can connect to Azure using ODBC or any of my versions of SSMS (I have 2012, 2014, 2016, and 2017 installed).